# Text color doesn't change on hover in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, button

I'm practising animations in CSS but somehow one of the buttons refuses to change.
It's the last button, all alone, that needs to have white text when you hover on it (and also white text when you click on it). I've tried some things but didn't work, who can help me? (Also I prefer not to use javascript)

Code can be find here: https://limoon.nl/test-animations/

Edit: It worked, thanks for all the tips!

Comment: If you do not add some code, this question may be closed, please add some code.

Comment: you need to post your html and css part here

Comment: Inspecting the code, I see the mistake. On `.LMbuttonBG:hover` you are actually changing the color of the button itself, not the `a` link that is inside of it. If you change the css rule to be `.LMbuttonBG:hover a` that should work.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you shouldn't have an anchor inside of a button. It's better to ditch the outer button and style the anchor with the same styles as a button.

The reason why the anchor isn't changing colour is because you are setting it here

```
/*link */
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will take precedent over the button hover styling

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a class for link inside the button like that.

```
.LMbuttonBG:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb to limit your use of !important in css rules.

Comment: Right! I copied a snip of code and I forget to remove it. However your answer in better and completed that mine.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use links within the button.

```
<button class="LMbuttonBG"><a href="https://limoon.nl/">Hover over mij</a></button>
```

Replace with this:

```
<button class="LMbuttonBG">Hover over mij</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently, in your code, the color style of  tag is black.
Like this and try it.

```
 .LMbuttonBG:hover, .LMbuttonBG:active, .LMbuttonBG:focus {
        background-color: black;
 }
    
 .LMbuttonBG:hover a, .LMbuttonBG:active a, .LMbuttonBG:focus a{
        color: #fff;
  }
```